# Why is array.fill() not extending my array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array holding a bunch of booleans and a function that adds *n* new booleans to it. All of them should start with their default value, so one way would be

```js
const array = [];

function extendArrayBy(amountOfNewItems) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amountOfNewItems; i++) {
    array.push(false);
  }
}

extendArrayBy(3);

console.log(array);
```

but there is a [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) function which might do it "more elegantly". I tried:

```js
let array = [];

const amountOfNewItems = 3;

array = array.fill(false, array.length, array.length + amountOfNewItems);

console.log(array);
```

Unfortunately the modified array does not contain the new items. Does someone know what I missed?

Comment: The `fill` method changes existing items, it does not add new items to an array (see first line in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said in the comments. [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) does not add new elements.

> The `fill()` method changes all elements in an array to a static value, from a start index (default 0) to an end index (default array.length). It returns the modified array.

You could change the `.length` before you call `fill`:

```js
let array = [true, false, true];

const amountOfNewItems = 3;

array.length = array.length + amountOfNewItems
array = array.fill(false, array.length - amountOfNewItems, array.length);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```js
let amountOfNewItems = 3;

let array = [];

array = array.concat(Array(amountOfNewItems).fill(false));
console.log(array);

let array2 = [1,2,3];

array2 = array2.concat(Array(amountOfNewItems).fill(false));
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that extends an array with a given value by a given amount.

```js
let arr = ['A', 1, {k: 'v'}];

/** Extends an array with a given *** value at a given amount.
* @param  {Array}  array
* @param  {Any}    element
* @param  {Number} size
* @return {Array}
*/
const extend = (array, element, size = 1) => {
  let extra = element == undefined ? null : element;
  const extArr = [...new Array(size)].map(e => extra); 
  return [...array, ...extArr];
};

console.log(extend(arr, false, 7));
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you do `[...new Array(size)].map(e => extra); ` instead of `new Array(size).map(e => extra); `

Comment: It's a habit from making NodeLists to Arrays, I do it on reflex.